# how to pass object between two controllers in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Actually I've googled to see how we can pass data from one `controller` to another in `Spring MVC` and I found that using `flash attributes` do the job.
It consists on declaring one controller  with `RequestMapping=GET` and an other with  `RequestMapping=POST`. I have tested this code in my controller and it worked.

```
 @RequestMapping(value ="/ajouter", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
     public String add(@ModelAttribute User user,final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {  
         redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("user", user);
      return "redirect:/account";  
     }
```

and the other:

```
 @RequestMapping(value ="/account", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
     public String addAccount(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,@ModelAttribute Account account) { 
                System.out.println(user.getId());

      return "account";  
     }
```

But I have another case: I have two `JSP`pages:
The first will add a user into the database. I want to recuperate the id of the user just inserted to set it as a foreign key for the account (after submitting the page for adding a user, a second page for adding an account appears).

I've tested this code:

This controller will insert a user into the database and recuperate the user which has been just inserted.

```
 @RequestMapping(value ="/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
     public String add(@ModelAttribute User user,final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {  
        this.userService.insertData(user);
         redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("user", user);
      return "redirect:/account";  
     }
```

and this controller will insert an account into the database, but can not recuperate the user id of the user just inserted.

```
     @RequestMapping(value= "/ajouterCompte", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCompte(@ModelAttribute("account") Account compte,@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
    System.out.println(user.getId());  //this code shows 0

    System.out.println(compte.getPwd());

     String hashPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(compte.getPwd());
     System.out.println(hashPassword);
     compte.setPwd(hashPassword);
    compte.setId(user.getId()); 
       this.compteService.insertCompte(compte);

    return "redirect:/users";

}
```

I guess that the problem is that the 2 controllers are declared  with a method `method = RequestMethod.POST` when it should be one `GET` and an other `POST`. But in this case how can I recuperate the id of the user so that it could be inserted into the database? 
When I declare the second controller with `GET`, the insertion of the database fails!

Need your help please :(

Comment: The problem is that the flash attributes is already cleared. It is only available for the first request, the post is the second request hence no more flash scope. Just add the user-id as a hidden field to your form and retrieve it as such. or in the GET method for displaying the account page (the method executed after the GET) re add the user as a flash attribute (bit dirty imho). I would probably create an `Account` in the get method and pre-fill the required fields passed on the user, then put those attributes in hidden fields in the form (or make Account a session attribute for the time).

Comment: thank you very much , you have saved my day !

Comment: could you please post it as a response so that I could mark your answer as the correct one ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object which are set as flash attributes are only available for the first request after those have been set. (As also explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes)).

Assuming that in your account controller you have a GET based method for `/account` pre-populate the `Account` with the information at that point.

```
public String account(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
    Account account = new Account();
    account.setId(user.getId());
    model.addAttribute("account", account);
    return "account";
}
```

Now you can either annotate your controller with `@SessionAttribute("account")` to have the `Account` stored in the session in between requests. If so then you have to modify your POST handling method to include a `SessionStatus` object and after storing call `setComplete()` on it.

```
public String addCompte(@ModelAttribute("account") Account compete, SessionStatus sessionStatus){
    ...
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

Or store the pre-filled information in hidden form fields so that it gets passed along with the following request and the `Account` can be reconstructed.

```
<form:hidden path="id" />
```